# Relative rotation on vr

Tags: unity-game-engine, 360-virtual-reality

I'm developing an app with unity that consists of a 360 video player. While watching the video, the user is sitted on a rotation chair synced with the movement of the video. 
The problem is, for example, if I have to rotate the chair because of the video than what the user will see is not the "front" of the video anymore,  so I'm searching a way to solve this problem. 
I have the heading of the chair inside my app, so I think that the best way is to block head-tracking while rotating but I don't know if there is the best way to do this.

Has anyone some suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> I think that the best way is to block head-tracking while rotating

The user should be in control and this kind of behaviour for VR immersive view will ruin the user experience (UX). It is like making a web-page and not allowing the user to move the mouse pointer for a while. Never do this.

The best you can do is to provide some guidance/clues so user rotates towards front/forward of the video **intuitively**.

Use some kind of glowy particles to get user's attention or use special audio to let the user know the direction to focus towards.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: But is not the user that move the chair. The chair itself turn around (left or right) based on video frame number. but if the chair turn, the POV of the user turn but it should not rotate. I hope I explained myself well
Thanks